# Mobilefirst preview on an android device stuck on IBM splash screen

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a hybrid app using IBM mobilefirst and ionic, with an iphone and android environment. When I try to preview the android application on a connected device as outlined [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/previewing-application-android/), the app is launched on the device, but it doesn't go any farther than the IBM splash screen. Is there something I've missed?

An error in the logcat console:

```
09-03 10:20:00.268: E/NONE(4936): [/apps/services/api/MyApp/android/init] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
```

My computer and the device are both on the same wifi network, if that matters.

Comment: It's better if you list the steps you are following rather than link to another page in case that page disappears in the future. That way your question might be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the host is unresponsive.

Did you try the suggestion from the error message?
If you open the stock browser app in the device and attempt to access http://localhost:10080/worklightconsole or http://your-ip:10080/worklightconsole - do you get to the console?

Perhaps you have several IP address available in your workstation? If you have several, attempt to assign one of them in the generated native project\assets\wlclient.properties file > host property.

Comment: Thanks, there are several IP addresses. I fixed that issue by Run As -> preview on the android project folder, which refreshes the IP to the one I'm currently using. This removes the error, however, the problem still persists.

I can also preview the app correctly using the chrome://inspect tool, but the device is still stuck on the IBM screen